# Edubuntu software for Windows

Tags: education

I need to install the Edubuntu software on Windows system not a Ubuntu system. Won't all the programs run on any system? How do I get just the Educational programs?

Comment: Ebuntu is an operating system, not an application. Could you specify which applications do you need from Ebuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Sepends on the application you are wanting. Some programs are available cross platform, firefox, thunderbird, audacious, audacity.

Other applications are going to be windows only.

You may be able to run some applications with cygwin, kde will run on windows for example.

But, in general, Ubuntu (Edubuntu) is an operating system and most programs are not going to run on Windows.

As edubuntu is intended to be more of a central server with (thin) clients, and you are running windows, my advice is to either dual boot, or perhaps a better solution, install ubuntu/edubuntu into VirtualBox.

Can you please update your question with more specific details of what applications you want to run ?

Comment: Oh. I thought anything that could run on Ubuntu could run on anything because it is an open platform. I was trying to get the Edubuntu math games, tux typing, math, etc. to run on Windows. I am losing Edubuntu on some of my lab computers because I can't reinstall it by booting from the Edubuntu ISO disk. When I lose all the machines with Edubuntu then even VirtualBox won't work for me

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make a list of all Software you want on a Windows System and manually Download them from their own Website, since I believe there is no Windows Installer that will install you every Edubuntu Application automatically.
You can just search the Websites via Google or http://www.duckduckgo.com .

For example Stellarium is available for Windows, Mac and Linux: http://stellarium.org/

Most educational software should be available for Windows too. If you provide a list of Applications you need, Users will surely help you to search Windows versions. Just edit the list into your question.

**What does not work:**
You can not copy the applications from an Ubuntu System and run it on Windows. You have to get the Windows-Version if available.